# How to pass multiple data to Go template?

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to pass two data objects to Go Template. One is a MongoDB query result and other is an integer array.

MongoDB Query:-

```
var results []User
sess, db := GetDatabase()
defer sess.Close()
c := db.C("user")
err := c.Find(nil).All(&results)
```

I want to sent 'result' and an int array through following code

```
GetTemplate("list").Execute(w,???????)
```

If there is only db result, we could use it as

```
GetTemplate("list").Execute(w,results)
```

and in template we could access it {{.Name}} etc. (where Name is a struct field of []User)

Please tell me how to pass these data and how to access them in template.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may only pass a single value, but that value may be a *composed* value of multiple values, e.g. a struct, map or slice. So simply wrap your multiple data intended for the template in a `struct` or in a `map`.

#### Example with a `struct`:

```
type Data struct {
    Results []User // Must be exported!
    Other   []int  // Must be exported!
}

data := &Data{results, []int{1, 2, 3}}
if err := GetTemplate("list").Execute(w, data); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Also note that a new, named type is not required, you could also use an anonymous struct literal, which could look like this:

```
data := struct {
    Results []User // Must be exported!
    Other   []int  // Must be exported!
}{results, []int{1, 2, 3}}
```

#### Example with a `map`:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "Results": results,
    "Other":   []int{1, 2, 3},
}

if err := GetTemplate("list").Execute(w, m); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

Note that using a map, it is not required to use capitalized `string`s as keys, e.g. you could've used `"results"` and `"other"` too (but in my opinion it's better to use keys with capital starting letters, should you move to `struct` sometimes in the future, you would have less corrections to make).

In both cases you may refer to the `[]User` results with `{{.Results}}` and to the additional int slice with `{{.Other}}`.

So for example to range over the users:

```
{{range .Results}}
    User name:{{.Name}}
{{end}}
```

#### Example with a `slice`:

```
s := []interface{}{
    results,
    []int{1, 2, 3},
}

if err := GetTemplate("list").Execute(w, s); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```

This is less readable, but a viable solution. In the template you have to index the template data to get the "individual" values, e.g.:

```
{{range index . 0}}
    User name:{{.Name}}
{{end}}

Other: {{index . 1}}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GLKPf0i5-o1).

#### Other ways...

There are other "theoretical" ways too, but I wouldn't use them just because it works.

For example, you could also pass in a channel from which receives would provide the values.

Yet another solution could be to [register custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550326/golang-templates-and-passing-funcs-to-template/35550730#35550730) which when called would return the values.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a struct populated with the database results query, then assign that struct to the `Execute` method.

`tmpl.Execute` require a `Writer` interface and a `struct`

```
type Inventory struct {
    Material string
    Count    uint
}

items := Inventory{"trouser", 1}    
if err := GetTemplate("list").Execute(w, items); err != nil {
    // ... do your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your structs inside another struct using the `range` keyword. e.g

```
type Data struct {
    Users  []User
    Developers []Developer
}


var data = Data{
    Users:  ...,
    Developers: ...,
}

err := t.Execute(w, &data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

{{range .Users}}{{.UserName}}
{{end}}
{{range .Developers}}{{.DeveloperName}}
{{end}}
```