# Golang templates (and passing funcs to template)

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I'm getting an error when I try and access a function I'm passing to my template:

```
Error: template: struct.tpl:3: function "makeGoName" not defined
```

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Template file (struct.tpl):

```
type {{.data.tableName}} struct {
  {{range $key, $value := .data.tableData}}
  {{makeGoName $value.colName}} {{$value.colType}} `db:"{{makeDBName $value.dbColName}},json:"{{$value.dbColName}}"`
  {{end}}
}
```

Calling file:

```
type tplData struct {
    tableName string
    tableData interface{}
}

func doStuff() {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/struct.tpl")
    if err != nil {
        errorQuit(err)
    }

    t = t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "makeGoName": makeGoName,
        "makeDBName": makeDBName,
    })

    data := tplData{
        tableName: tableName,
        tableData: tableInfo,
    }

    t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
}

func makeGoName(name string) string {
    return name
}

func makeDBName(name string) string {
    return name
}
```

This is for a program that generates struct boilerplate code (in case anyone is wondering why I'm doing that in my template).

Comment: You need to add the functions (i.e. calling `t.Funcs`) before parsing with `ParseFiles`. To do this get a fresh template via `New()`, then add your funcs than parse the files into it. (Untested)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Custom functions need to be registered before parsing the templates, else the parser would not be able to tell whether an identifier is a valid function name or not. Templates are designed to be statically analyzable, and this is a requirement to that.

You can first create a new, undefined template with [`template.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#New), and besides the [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) *function*, the [`template.Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template) type (returned by `New()`) also has a [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.ParseFiles) *method*, you can call that.

Something like this:

```
t, err := template.New("struct.tpl").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "makeGoName": makeGoName,
    "makeDBName": makeDBName,
}).ParseFiles("templates/struct.tpl")
```

When `template.ParseFiles()` is used, the call to `template.New()` call must specify the basename of the file that is being executed.

Also [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute) returns an [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), print that to see if no output is generated, e.g.:

```
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear. I'm not getting any errors now, but strangely there's no output. I outputted it to a bytes.Buffer to test that it is indeed empty, and the bytes.Buffer is also empty. Any idea why that might be, or how I can debug this when I have no output or errors?

Comment: Pass the "struct.tpl" string to the `New` function. From the doc: Since the templates created by ParseFiles are named by the base names of the argument files, t should usually have the name of one of the (base) names of the files. If it does not, depending on t's contents before calling ParseFiles, t.Execute may fail. In that case use t.ExecuteTemplate to execute a valid template.

Comment: @PéterSzakszon your comment is actually required. Otherwise, you'll get an error that `template: : "" is an incomplete or empty template`

Comment: `template.New("")`, "" need to be defined, if not this will make error `template: : "" is an incomplete or empty template`, and the Name must equal to filename

Comment: @gumelaragum Yes, if you parse the template text from a `string`. But in my examples I don't do that, I call `Template.ParseFiles()`.

Answer (score 7):

When registering custom functions for your template and using `ParseFiles()` you need to specify the name of the template when instantiating it and executing it. You also need to call `ParseFiles()` after you call `Funcs()`.

```golang
// Create a named template with custom functions
t, err := template.New("struct.tpl").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "makeGoName": makeGoName,
    "makeDBName": makeDBName,
}).ParseFiles("templates/struct.tpl") // Parse the template file
if err != nil {
    errorQuit(err)
}

// Execute the named template
err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "struct.tpl", data)
if err != nil {
    errorQuit(err)
}
```

When working with named templates the name is the filename without the directory path e.g. `struct.tpl` not `templates/struct.tpl`. So the name in `New()` and `ExecuteTemplate()` should be the string `struct.tpl`.

Comment: Not sure why Go developers went with this but this pattern seems to be counterintuitive. For example, in case I am taking the template path from user in the command line as a flag, say something like "templates/index.html", I have to extract the file name "index.html" from the path in order to provide it later to execute the HTML generation.