# Syntax for creating struct map key in Go HTML template

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm writing a simple Go program to display an HTML table of deployed service versions per environment. My program contains the following structs:

```
type versionKey struct {
    Environment string
    Service     string
}

type templateData struct {
    Environments []string
    Services     []string
    Versions     map[versionKey]string
}
```

As you can see, the `Versions` map uses a `versionKey` as a key for a string value e.g. `"1.0.0"`.

I'm passing the `templateData` struct to an HTML template and ranging over its `Environments` and `Services` slices to build the HTML table. The problem is that I need to construct a `versionKey` for any given intersection of environment and service so I can use it to look up the version from the `Versions` map and output that value in the table cell.

Within the template I have `$environment` and `$service` variables available from the ranges, but I can't work out the Go template syntax to create the `versionKey` struct.

Here's the template code with the markup omitted:

```
{{$environments := .Environments}}
{{$services := .Services}}
{{$versions := .Versions}}

{{range $service := $services}}
  ...
  {{range $environment := $environments}}
    ...
    {{index $versions ...? }} // How to create versionKey struct map key here?
    ...
  {{end}}
  ...
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only template code you can't. You need some kind of support from the executing Go code to do that. By design philosophy, templates should not contain complex logic. You may argue whether this is complex, but the template syntax has no support for this.

Simplest solution would be to add a `Version()` method to the `templateData` struct, which would simply return the version for a given environment and service:

```
func (t *templateData) Version(environment, service string) string {
    return t.Versions[versionKey{
        Environment: environment,
        Service:     service,
    }]
}
```

Using this from the template:

```
{{range $service := $services -}}
  {{range $environment := $environments}}
    {{$environment}} - {{$service}} version: {{$.Version $environment $service}}
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Testing it:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
td := &templateData{
    Environments: []string{"EnvA", "EnvB"},
    Services:     []string{"ServA", "ServB"},
    Versions: map[versionKey]string{
        {"EnvA", "ServA"}: "1.0.0",
        {"EnvA", "ServB"}: "1.0.1",
        {"EnvB", "ServA"}: "1.0.2",
    },
}
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, td); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7ytztACizl)):

```
EnvA - ServA version: 1.0.0

EnvB - ServA version: 1.0.2


EnvA - ServB version: 1.0.1

EnvB - ServB version:
```

#### Alternatives

Instead of the `templateData.Version()` method you could just as easily register a function which could create and return a value of type `versionKey` from a given environment and service. See [`Template.Funcs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) for details. This would be more complicated though, but more flexible as this could be reused elsewhere. See an example of this here: [Golang templates (and passing funcs to template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550326/golang-templates-and-passing-funcs-to-template/35550730#35550730). A slight variation of this would be to pass a function value as any other template data instead of registering it as a named function, which can be called.

Another alternative would be to "transform" your `Versions` field into a map of maps, e.g.:

```
Versions map[string]map[string]string
```

Which first could be indexed by environment, then by service, which in the template you can achieve by 2 `{{index}}` actions. You would have to check if the first indexing yields any results though.

Comment: A superb answer, many thanks. Out of interest, why did you use a pointer for `templateData`?

Comment: @JohnTopley Both (pointer and non-pointer receiver) would work in this simple example. I used pointer receiver out of sheer habit, if the example evolves into a more complex one where methods also need to mutate / modify the receiver, I don't have to go back and change receivers to pointer ones.