# Go Templates: two or more slices ranges

Tags: templates, go, range, slice

The next code works perfect for output one slice inside the HomeTemplate.

main.go

```
type Item struct {
    Id          int
    Name string
    Type      string
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("tmpl/*"))

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    db := database.DbConn()

    selDB, err := product.ByID()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    i := Item{}

    resItems := []Item{}

    for selDB.Next() {

        var id int
        var product_name, product_type string

        err = selDB.Scan(&id, &product_name, &product_type)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        i.Id = id
        i.Name = product_name
        i.Type = product_type

        resItems = append(resItems, i)

    }

    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "HomeTemplate", resItems)

    // Close database connection
    defer db.Close()
}
```

In the template forks fine the next code:

```
{{ range . }}
    {{ .Name }}<br />
{{ end }}
```

Why something like this does not work?

```
{{ range .resItems }}
    {{ .Name }}<br />
{{ end }}
```

What if I want output two or more slices, what I need to do or change?

Thank you

Comment: *What if I want output two or more slices, what I need to do or change?*  You need to pass a data structure to `ExecuteTemplate` that can contain multiple pieces of data, such as a struct.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [How to pass multiple data to Go template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224066/how-to-pass-multiple-data-to-go-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first question, why `rang .resItems` doesn't work.
In template, `.` means current item. like `this` in java. 
if `.` in some direction like `range`, it means the item from `range` operation.
if not, it means the item you passed form `ExecuteTemplate()` method. like in `ExecuteTemplate(w, "HomeTemplate", resItems)`, `.` means `resItems`. so you can not use `.resItems` because it means `resItems` have a value called `resItems`.

second, if you have more slices to pass to template, you can add all of them to a map, like this:

```
t := template.New("test")
t, _ = t.Parse(`
test range 
{{range .first}} {{.}} {{end}}
{{range .second}} {{.}} {{end}}
`)
var res = make(map[string]interface{})
aa := []string{"first", "second"}
bb := []string{"123", "456"}
res["first"] = aa
res["second"] = bb
t.Execute(os.Stdout, res)

// output
test range
 first  second
 123  456
```

I have two array aa and bb, and add them to a map then pass it to the template. In template, `.` means the map, and `.first` got the array aa. and so as bb.

Hope this can help you...

Comment: Thank you, and that means that all the data that I need to pass to the templates need must be in the map, right?

Comment: Yes, map or a struct