# Passing elements from range loop to a html block

Tags: go, go-templates

I defined this block using go HTML templates:

`{{define "button"}}<button> . </button>{{end}}`

I would like to use this block as a nested block and I would like to pass arguments to it.

Is it possible to pass elements from iteration to the above block?

````
{{range $val := .}}
  {{template "button" . /* <!╌ I would like to pass $val here ╌> */}}
{{end}}
</body>```
````

Comment: `{{template "button" $val}}` or `{{range := . }} {{template "button" .}} {{end}}`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to pass not only argument from range loop but also entire context?
I mean in this case:
{{range $val := .fruits}}
  {{template "button" . /* <!╌ I would like to pass $val here but also everything what is under dot  ╌> */}}
{{end}}

Comment: `{{range}}` sets the dot to the iteration values. Use the `$` to refer to outer values, e.g. `$.` to the passed element of the (outer) template.

Comment: Is it possible to pass both: outer value and iteration value?

Comment: [How to pass multiple values from template to template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473199/how-to-pass-multiple-values-from-template-to-template/49475057#49475057)